# How to clear html page before showing into a webview in Android?

Tags: android, url, webview, jsoup, data-cleaning

I have the URL of a webpage to be displayed into a webview in my Android app. Before showing this page i want to clear the html code of this page from some tag (such as the header, footer, ecc..) in order to show only few information. How can i do it? I tried to solve the issue working with JSoup but i can't understand how to create and pass the "new page" to the webview. Anybody can help me?

EDIT

I cleaned the html code useless through jsoup libraries. Then, always by mean of these, i get head and body content and finally i showing the "cleared" web page through these lines:

```
headURL = doc.select("head").outerHtml();
bodyURL = doc.select("body").outerHtml();

webview.loadData( "<html>"+headURL+bodyURL+"</html>" , "text/html", "charset=UTF-8");

webview.setWebViewClient(new DisPlayWebPageActivityClient());
```

The view shows the new page but do not load css files specified in the head(that has not been touched). Who can say me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the WebPage you want to display as a string, parse and remove whatever you don't want and then load this string as data in your webview.

Something like:

```
String webContent = fetchPage(url);
String cleanedWebContent = cleanUp(webContent);
webView.loadData(cleanedWebContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Of course, you will need to implement `fetchPage` and `cleanUp` as they are not Android methods

Comment: Great, is just what i needed! I implement this solution, but i still have some issue. The webview load my custom html code but it seems like it is not loading the css file, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @FrancescoLombardo, Where is the CSS file coming from ? Internet ? You might need to use `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` to load your HTML.

Comment: @JonasCz yes the entire url is coming from internet... Can you post an example on how to use this method?

Comment: @FrancescoLombardo Use it like `loadDataWithBaseURL(myBaseUrl, cleanedWebContent,  "text/html", "UTF-8", null)` myBaseUrl is a String, the _original_ URL where the HTML page came from.

Comment: Also, if you have access to original HTML file try to use relative routes in CSS reference. For example:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./theme.css">`